# Keras-viz throwing InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am running a simple CNN model in Keras. Code:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import keras

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Activation, Input
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 1

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='preds'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

I want to visualize the dense layers. For this, I am using [keras-vis](https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis/)

While running the following code:

```py
from vis.visualization import visualize_activation
from vis.utils import utils
from keras import activations
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (18, 6)

# Utility to search for layer index by name. 
# Alternatively we can specify this as -1 since it corresponds to the last layer.
layer_idx = utils.find_layer_idx(model, 'preds')

# Swap softmax with linear
model.layers[layer_idx].activation = activations.linear
model = utils.apply_modifications(model)

# This is the output node we want to maximize.
filter_idx = 0
img = visualize_activation(model, layer_idx, filter_indices=filter_idx)
plt.imshow(img[..., 0])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: conv2d_2_input_2:0 is both fed and fetched.
```

Solutions that I have tried

- Installing Keras-vis from source for the latest build
- Applying Changes from PR mentioned in issues

Version:

- Keras : 2.7
- Keras-Vis : 0.5